# NextJS: Cannot Build The Project

Tags: node.js, next.js, plesk, iisnode

In my local PC I can build my project just fine with `next build`.

In my hosting service (IIS Node with Plesk), it fails. This is the error:

```
warn  - You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment. This creates inconsistencies in the project and is strongly advised against. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env
(node:10036) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of D:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\yyy.com\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of D:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\yyy.com\node_modules\react-icons\ai\index.esm.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of D:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxx.com\yyy.com\node_modules\react-icons\io5\index.esm.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
```

My local PC uses Node 16, in the hosting server it uses Node 12. Is this because of the Node version? Or is there something else which causes this error?

Comment: what version of webpack you are using?

Comment: Irrespective of the error, you'd want to have your local Node.js version match the version used on the server where you host/deploy the app. Can you increase the Node.js version on the server to match your local one?

Comment: Thats the problem, I do not have the control to change the server's version. I am trying to figure out whether the problem causes by mismatching version. If yes then I probably should change my server.